# Modal Dialog Auto-scrolls to Top

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

**HTML**

```
        <div class="modal fade" id="pleaseWaitDialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    Calculating...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="spinner"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    var dialog = $('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal({
        keyboard: false,
        backdrop: 'static',
        show: false
    });

    //A checkbox
    $('body').on('change', '.Foo', function () {            
        dialog.modal('show');
        //Updates a Highchart using this.checked and this.id
        dialog.modal('hide');
    });
```

Above is a piece of code that allows me to update a `highchart` on click of a `checkbox` belonging to class `Foo`. During updating, it pops up a `modal`, updates the `highChart` and closes the `modal`. The problem is, just before the `modal` opens, the body auto-scrolls to the top of the page, which I do not want to happen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What library are you using for this `dialog.modal` function?

Comment: @RGraham Added the definition of `dialog`. Apologies

Comment: Is this bootstrap? If so, what version?